# Is this function vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I built a function to check if a table exists on a database using PDO, but I'm not sure if I've secured it properly.

```
public function tableExists($table){
    try{
        $this->query('SELECT 1 FROM `'.str_replace('`', '', $table).'` LIMIT 1');
    }catch(\PDOException $e){
        if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1146){
            return false;
        }
        throw $e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is it possible for an attacker to compromise the query if `$table` is provided directly from user input? (extreme case)

Comment: I would print that $table with addslashes(), just in case.

Comment: @MilanG: What on Earth do you imagine that would accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## NO, your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection attack

**However, that is perhaps more by fluke than anything else.**

To handle user-provided values correctly, one would normally wish to *escape* any characters that have special meaning (rather than simply remove them).  As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifier quote characters can be included within an identifier if you quote the identifier. If the character to be included within the identifier is the same as that used to quote the identifier itself, then you need to double the character. The following statement creates a table named `` a`b `` that contains a column named `c"d`:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE `a``b` (`c"d` INT);
> ```

So how can we permit *any* table name, including those that contain backtick characters?

## Permissive escaping—attempt 1

You might be tempted to modify your function to use the following:

```php
$this->query('SELECT 1 FROM `'.str_replace('`', '``', $table).'` LIMIT 1');
```

### DON'T! The above code *is* vulnerable (in obscure edge cases).

[`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is a naive, byte-wise function (it is not character-set aware, and therefore is not safe to use with string encodings that have multi-byte characters).

If your database connection uses a multibyte character set, such as GBK, then a malicious table name would not get escaped properly:

```php
// malicious user-provided value
$_POST['tableName'] = "\x8c`; DROP TABLE users; -- ";

// call your function with that value
tableExists($_POST['tableName']);
```

The above would result in `query()` being called with the following string argument:

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM `宍`; DROP TABLE users; -- ` LIMIT 1
```

This is because when `str_replace()` goes through the inputted string byte-by-byte—naively replacing any occurrence of the `` '`' `` character, i.e. byte `0x60`—it does so without understanding that MySQL will consider the string to be encoded using GBK, in which `0x8c60` is the single character `'宍'`; and therefore it turns such characters into `0x8c6060` which represent `` '宍`' ``.  That is `str_replace()` has introduced a terminating backtick character that was not there before!

## Permissive escaping—attempt 2

The problem can however be fixed by using a character-set aware replacement function.  PHP *doesn't have one by default*, although some optional extensions like [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) are fairly commonplace in typical hosting environments.

If following this approach, you *must* ensure that you perform the replacement using *the character encoding of the database connection*.

## Permissive escaping—attempt 3

As of MySQL v5.7.6, you can use [`mysql_real_escape_string_quote()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html) to properly escape SQL identifiers using the database connection's character set.  Sadly however, the PDO API does not (yet?) provide an interface to this C function…

## What about whitelisting?

Whitelisting is often considered to be more secure and reliable than escaping.  However (unless one knows in advance that they do not contain special characters), *one must still escape the whitelisted values*—so this doesn't really help progress the most general cases, although it does limit the damage that can be done should the escaping prove erroneous.

## So what's the conclusion?

It's actually quite **difficult** to use arbitrary, user-provided, SQL identifiers in a safe way.

Fortunately, however, it's not a common requirement.  As a general rule, one's schema should both be static (absent any changes to one's codebase that necessitate schema modification) *and* compliant with the [principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design): if both of those conditions are fulfilled, SQL identifiers will always be part of one's static code and there will not be any need to use user input in their place.

Comment: That is one great answer, thank you, sir! This function is a part of a little personal framework project, it is not going to be fed user input, but I just gave it as an example as the worst possible case. What I figure out from what you've written is that I'd be best off simply not allowing back ticks in table names, I hope I'm not wrong though, but the very first statement of yours comforts me into believing I'm not.

Comment: @EmilioRodrigues: You must not only prevent tables names containing backtick, but also *any character that encodes with a `0x60` byte in any character set that might be used by the database client*.  If you **insist** on having a dynamic schema (which, for the reasons mentioned in my conclusion, is rather unusual and often indicative of **very bad design**), then you'd probably do well to fix your escaping so that all identifiers are handled properly (rather than risk munging them by stripping out valid characters simply because correct escaping is too challenging)!

Comment: I just went through a full list of utf8 characters and determined that there are no other characters that end in `60` and actually none that have `60` in their encoded representation. In my practice I've never met a need to use another character set and probably never will. So assuming these, probably absurd, limitations I will safely say I'm set with the code I currently have, supporting utf8 only.

Comment: I just want to thank you once again, because these byte-games were a matter I've been wanting to dig into for a long time but never knew how to approach to actually understand. You've helped me a great lot, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No. You have removed the only harmful character in the given context.

So it's safe.

As for *reasonable*, well... no. Table names are generally something that should never come from user input.

Comment: What is generally the problem with table name coming from user input, if it cannot harm the system?

Comment: It's a sign that your database design may not be ideal, for one. Although really it depends on the application. There are cases where it's good, so I can't say without knowing.